# git commits are missing from file history after merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

Some files in my project are using their old versions (I've committed and pushed changes to these files but these commits do not show up in file history log).

I can pinpoint the problem to a faulty merge committed by a team-mate. I don't know how it happened but the merge must've reset the versions of some files. Reverting the merge doesn't work because the files that got reverted to their old versions are not part of the changeset.

How can I fix this problem so that the files use their latest version?

`git log -- <filename>` shows only the commits up to the old version

`git log -- full-history -- <filename>` shows all the commits up to the latest version

I want the files to use the full history.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to checkout the modified files to the version you want to use and commit them again. To do that:

1. Identify the commit you want to use for these files, by browsing the `git log --full-history` output
2. Checkout the files in your local repo to that commit with `git checkout <commit_hash> file1 file2`
3. Add and commit those modifications as a new commit
4. Push the modifications